# Proof that an short exact sequence splits if the vector spaces are finite dimensional

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, exact-sequence

I've been reading Harvey Rose's book on Linear Algebra, and I am stuck trying to understand this proof.

The short exact sequence is $ \{0\} \rightarrow U \rightarrow^f V \rightarrow^g W \rightarrow \{0\}$

To prove it splits, they say:

Let $\{w_1,...,w_n\}$ be a basis for W. Choose $v_i\in V$ so that $v_i$ is a preimage of $w_i$ under the map $g$, which can happen because $g$ is surjective.
Now they say that there will exist a map $h: W \rightarrow V$ with the property that $h(w_i)=v_i$ for all $i$ and that $goh$ is the identity map.

Here's my problem:

I understood that there will exist a $v_i$ for each $w_i$ because $g$ is a surjection, but how does that imply that $h$ exists? Will not $g$ have to be one to one as well? Or isn't it necessary that V and W have the same dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget that $\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ is a basis of $W$. Therefore, for *any* vector space $Z$ and for *any* vectors $z_1,\ldots,z_n\in Z$, there is one (and only one) linear map $f\colon W\longrightarrow Z$ such that$$(\forall k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}):f(w_k)=z_k.$$That's all you need.

Comment: Thank you so much!